# goto inside switch case working weirdly

Tags: c, switch-statement, goto

This is a code to the data in inputfile to a new file and if an output file already exists the user will have option to either provide new address or exit.
when I place the `goto readout` inside switch, the switch and goto work but after that program exits without taking the output file address.
This is the screenshot:
[image: this is the screenshot of program output]

And the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    FILE *in,*out;
    char inadd[50],outadd[50],ch;
    readin:

    printf("Enter the address of input file: ");  
    gets(inadd);
    in=fopen(inadd,"r");
    if(in==NULL)                 //reading and validating input file address
    {
        printf("There is an error with the opening of the file, please reenter the file name.\n");
        goto readin;            //readin call
    }
    readout:

    printf("Enter the address of output file: ");
    gets(outadd);
    out=fopen(outadd,"r");
    if(out!=NULL)            //reading and validating output file address
    {
        printf("File already exists, to reenter file address enter 1 & to exit enter 2:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        switch (n)                 //switc-case
        {
            case 1: printf("\n");
                    goto readout;  //readout call
                    break;
            case 2: exit(0);
        }

    }else              //file is read and copied to input file.
    {
        out=fopen(outadd,"w");
        while(!feof(in))
        {
            fscanf(in,"%c",&ch);
            fprintf(out,"%c",ch);
        }
        fclose(in);
        fclose(out);
        printf("\n\nSuccess!\nFile copied successfully\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a do...While loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code below. The reason being is that scanf leave newline in your buffer and `gets` pick that up.

```
printf("File already exists, to reenter file address enter 1 & to exit enter 2:");
scanf("%d",&n);
int c;    
do {
    c = getchar();
}while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that no one should ever use `gets`.